# Synchronicity of Azure stored procedures

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We know that stored procedures are ACID atomic, but are they synchronous?

Until Microsoft Azure Cosmos team updates the API to allow partial UPDATEs as opposed to the current SELECT only statement allowed, one of the solutions for this is running sprocs to access the items via javascript.

Is there some sort of semaphore that will queue the calls to stored procedures? I'm asking because I wanted to add some sprocs to update some items, but even if atomic I'm afraid if several instances of the same sprocs execute at the same time one will succeed but others may fail if they try to update the item after the first instance did it. Because of the atomicity we guarantee no partial states but that doesn't guarantee there won't be update errors. Are sprocs synchronous? Are they put in a queue?

Comment: FYI…Partial updates are now supported in Cosmos DB.

Comment: No. It is only a private review. I'm not getting into a list to implement something whose availability is undefined

Comment: FYI this question has been answered before (see the link in the 'duplicate' notice) - that particular question+answer refers to DocumentDB, as that was the original service name before it evolved to Cosmos DB several years ago.